# Wrapping right margin doesn't work

Tags: phpstorm

I want to move wrap line to the right. I set option in `Settings | Editor | Code Style | PHP` on the `Wrapping and Braces` and also `Settings | Code Style | General | Right margin (columns)`, press Apply and no changes.

Can you help me guys? Is there plugin which do that and I turned it off?

Comment: 1) No need to do it in both places -- either general or PHP specific; 2) PhpStorm version used? 3) Screenshots please (of your settings + the line (margin) visible in editor where it would be clear at what position it is) 4) Have you tried with all 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins disabled?

Answer (score 0):

The number you put in `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Right margin (columns)` is the default value, for all file type. You can override it for PHP in `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> PHP -> Wrapping and Braces -> Right margin (columns)` but you already know that.

The value is used when PhpStorm reformats your code (when you explicitly use the command `Code -> Reformat Code` from the menu, when you paste some code and also when you use the commands from the `Refactor` menu). If you want it to wrap the code as you type it you have to also check `Wrap on typing` (it is located next to `Right margin (columns)` and can be overridden in the same way.